# pandas vs. datetime: calculating time deltas between timezone-aware datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

On the one hand, for performance requirements, I'm using `pandas` to compute time difference between 2 timezone-aware datetimes, that is to say between 2 timezone-aware [`pandas.Timestamp` objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html).

On the other hand, for testing purposes (mainly), I'm using exclusively the Python `datetime` module. The idea was to achieve the same result with 2 different pieces of code.

My issue is that the time difference calculation turns out not to be the same in `pandas` and in the `datetime` module of Python. Here's an illustration of my point:

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import datetime
import pandas as pd

utc = ZoneInfo(key='UTC')

d1 = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
d2 = datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))

p1 = pd.Timestamp(d1)
p2 = pd.Timestamp(d2)

# with the datetime module, this is True...
d2 - d1 != d2.astimezone(utc) - d1.astimezone(utc)
# but with pandas, it isn't...
p2 - p1 != p2.astimezone(utc) - p1.astimezone(utc)
# ⚠ thus, this is False and my tests fail!
d2 - d1 == p2 - p1
```

How can I change the behavior of either the `pandas` or the `datetime` module for my tests to pass? Is there another solution than adding `.astimezone()` everywhere? For instance, a default setting to update somewhere?

Also, to better understand the root of this inconsistency, what are the differences between the implementation of the `timedelta` calculation in `pandas` and in `datetime`?

Please note that I'm also using Django and I would like to avoid resorting to `pytz` because [it was replaced by `zoneinfo` in Django 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones#time-zones-overview).

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right because I've noticed other unexpected behaviors regarding some `pd.Timestamp` instances built from `zoneinfo` timezone-aware `datetime.datetime`. I'll check the `pandas` methods but regarding my code I'm affraid it will imply many changes in any case. Do you know where I could learn more about `pandas` support for `zoneinfo`?

Comment: I might be wrong / outdated here, at least [this merge](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/46425) suggests so.

Comment: If you assume Python's timedelta arithmetic (time difference as on a wall clock), it seems like pandas doesn't follow that concept; datetime says the difference between the two date/times is 184 days (as I would expect) while pandas says 183 days, 23 hours (so that includes the DST transition hour). Maybe this is due to compatibility with numpy's timedelta, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: Indeed, as discussed below, it's just a matter of point of view: both implementations make sense in a way, but in my case more consistency between the 2 libraries would be great 

Comment: I agree, this should be consistent. One might like Python's concept or not but if pandas diverts from it, they should be more clear in [their docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) and clarify what they mean by "*Timedelta is a subclass of datetime.timedelta, and behaves in a similar manner*". ***similar*** sounds a bit vague in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can try some thing like 
date=datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0,)
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(date, tz='Europe/Paris') #Convert timezone of timestamp.
print(timestamp)

after looking into p1 and p2 and trying to find the difference i found out this :
print(p1,p2)
print(d1,d2)
print(p2.astimezone(utc))
print(d2.astimezone(utc))
print(d1.astimezone(utc))
print(p1.astimezone(utc))
print(p2.astimezone(utc) - p1.astimezone(utc))
print(p2 - p1)
print(d2-d1)
print(d2.astimezone(utc) - d1.astimezone(utc))

2023-03-01 00:00:00+01:00 2023-09-01 00:00:00+02:00
2023-03-01 00:00:00+01:00 2023-09-01 00:00:00+02:00
2023-08-31 22:00:00+00:00
2023-08-31 22:00:00+00:00
2023-02-28 23:00:00+00:00
2023-02-28 23:00:00+00:00
183 days 23:00:00
183 days 23:00:00
184 days, 0:00:00
183 days, 23:00:00

# if you can see the difference between both p1 and p2 also d1 d2 its slightly  #different :
#184 days, 0:00:00
#183 days, 23:00:00 

date=datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0,)
date2=datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 1, 0, 0,)
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(date, tz='Europe/Paris') #Convert timezone of timestamp.
timestamp2 = pd.Timestamp(date2, tz='Europe/Paris')
so p2-p1 == timestamp2-timestamp
```

Comment: Indeed, there is 1-hour time difference which can be explained by the Central European Summer Time: both implementations are right, it's just a matter of point of view... But this doesn't address my issue, does it?

Comment: i think if you can use :date=datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0,)
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(date, tz='Europe/Paris') for value of p1

Comment: see the last line if that useful